# why is my box returning to origin only when slide to right

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, animation

I have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
    <translate
 android:fromXDelta="0%p"
     android:toXDelta="30%p"
     android:duration="600">

    </translate>
</set>
```

and this class:

```
switch_bg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (!isChecked) {

                    Animation animation = android.view.animation.AnimationUtils
                            .loadAnimation(AppService.getAppContext(),
                                    com.waze.R.anim.slide_to_right);

                    animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
                    animation.setFillAfter(true);
                    boxImage_left.startAnimation(animation);

                    AlphaAnimation alpha = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
                    alpha.setDuration(1000);

                    alpha.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
                    alpha.setFillAfter(true);
                    vImage_left.startAnimation(alpha);

                } else {
                    Animation animation = android.view.animation.AnimationUtils
                            .loadAnimation(AppService.getAppContext(),
                                    com.waze.R.anim.slide_to_left);

                    animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
                    animation.setFillAfter(true);
                    boxImage_left.startAnimation(animation);

                    AlphaAnimation alpha = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
                    alpha.setDuration(1000);

                    alpha.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
                    alpha.setFillAfter(true);
                    vImage_left.startAnimation(alpha);
                }

                TransitionDrawable transition = (TransitionDrawable) switch_bg
                        .getBackground();
                transition.reverseTransition(TRANSITION_TIME);

                isChecked = !isChecked;

            }
        });
    }
```

when I move the box right-to-left it stays there after animation,

but after animation left-to-right it returns to origin position on the left.

How come?

I use `alpha.setFillAfter(true);` on both cases.

**update**

strangely if I cancel the setFillAfter for alpha animation,

the sliding transition stays OK at the end. How come? these are two different transition objects.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it you need only a single tween animation at a time on a view; you should be able to express the alpha animation in the xml too. This would solve your problem; should be reliable across all android versions (I'm not sure your current solution always looks right); and simplify the code.